# how to read bytes from a video file in android

Tags: android

I have a question that I want to read bytes from video resided in sdcard in chunk size 1024,
means I have to read 1024 bytes from the file at a time. I am able to fetch number of bytes from the video but I can't get it in chunks, I don't know how to achieve this. Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same as reading from any other file--look for any Java file input tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileUtil {
    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    public void readFile(String fileName) {

        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        try {
            int n = 0;
            while ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
                /* do whatever you want with buffer here */
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally { // always close input stream
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the code from http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/648/

Comment: The code is fine, but I can't fathom why something like that would belong in a static utility method.